# Android: Trouble requesting permissions to make a phone call

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm making an app which dials out based on the country selected. However, for some countries the app places a direct call (which is what I want) but for some other country selections, the dialler is opened and I am having to place the call manually. Sometimes the dialler crashes on opening too. Why is this happening?

My code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_page);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      callPermission();
    }
}

public void CurrentCountry (View view) {

    final CharSequence[] items = {"UK", "USA", "France","Germany"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Select your current country");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("UK")) {
                TextView Dialout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dialout);
                Dialout.setText("12345678");

            } else if (items[item].equals("USA")) {
                TextView Dialout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dialout);
                Dialout.setText("87654321");

            } else if (items[item].equals("France")) {                  
                TextView Dialout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dialout);
                Dialout.setText("1111111111");
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void call1 () {
    try {

        TextView dialnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dialout);
        String text = dialnum.getText().toString();
        final Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+text)); 
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {

    }
}


public void MakeCall (View view){

    call1();
}

private void callPermission () {

  checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                1);
        return;
    }
}

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace

```
05-18 11:55:00.618 15097-15097/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-18 11:55:00.663 15097-15097/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.es.bt.diallerapp-1/lib/arm
05-18 11:55:00.694 15097-15105/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
05-18 11:55:00.697 15097-15112/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-18 11:55:00.725 15097-15112/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (Ia6c73e7530)
                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
                                           Build Date: 12/04/15 Fri
                                           Local Branch: mybranch17080070
                                           Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.5
                                           Local Patches: NONE
                                           Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
05-18 11:55:00.726 15097-15112/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-18 11:55:05.696 15097-15112/com.es.bt.diallerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3992580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb35f4470
05-18 11:55:12.176 15097-15112/com.es.bt.diallerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3992580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb35f4490
05-18 11:55:17.046 15097-15112/com.es.bt.diallerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3992580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb35f4a20
05-18 11:55:22.207 15097-15112/com.es.bt.diallerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3992580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb35f4a90
05-18 11:55:38.018 15097-15112/com.es.bt.diallerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3992580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb35f4ab0
05-18 11:56:15.284 15097-15112/com.es.bt.diallerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9e9c8580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb35f4a20
05-18 11:56:15.802 15097-15097/com.es.bt.diallerapp E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.es.bt.diallerapp/com.es.bt.diallerapp.FirstActivity}
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.es.bt.diallerapp/com.es.bt.diallerapp.FirstActivity}
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3509)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-18 11:56:48.348 15097-15097/com.es.bt.diallerapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
05-18 11:56:48.349 15097-15097/com.es.bt.diallerapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-18 11:56:48.349 15097-15097/com.es.bt.diallerapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
05-18 11:56:48.350 15097-15097/com.es.bt.diallerapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Open dialler by intent not need to request any permission.

You should show the StackTrace when your app crashes for more accurate answer.

Comment: @Ken I don't want to open dialler. I want to make direct call. Please check my edit for StackTrace. This is a strange problem i'm facing. For one selection, the call is placed normally, but for a different selection, the dialler is opened. The dialler sometimes force closes and crashes my app too (captured in StackTrace as `java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed`)

Comment: That Exception often happens when your FirstActivity opens its self in onCreate or onResume (so it will loop infinitely) or you call finish() in onPause() or onDestroy()... Please update your real code of FirstActivity and Manifest. I want to see where MakeCall and CurrentCountry functions was called and what you handler when permissions are granted.